# Is "How do I read/interpret X command output?" a fair question?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I love wondershaper, as it prevents me from abusing my little cheap bandwidth/router, but when I try to know how it does I'm suddenly immersed into tc output which looks alien to me and left me with this bad taste that I couldn't get rid of.

Through the manual of tc is complete in the "usage" part, it lacks of information in the "how to check how awesome I am fairing" department (the statistics section is one line long). Can I ask this question or should I drown myself in documentation (I'm sure is somewhere, but whenever I google for it I only find how to create and manage the rules)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've looked at the official documentation and you don't understand it or it doesn't have the information you want, then sure, go ahead and ask. That's kinda the whole point of having Stack Exchange.